# Apache Reverse Proxy - ProxyPass based on HTTP body

Tags: apache, soap, reverse-proxy

I have systems issuing SOAP requests to my Apache Reverse Proxy, and I have two distinct applications which should handle these requests. The differentiation is, however, done on the requests' SOAP bodies:

- Whenever the incoming request contains a specific XML Tag in the body, send it to server_a:port/endpoint
- Whenever the incoming request does not contain that specific XML Tag in the body, send it to server_b:port/endpoint

Note that the incoming request URLs are the same. The only difference is the actual SOAP body of the incoming requests.

I've already found ways to do that by checking the incoming request URL POST parameters ([Conditional ProxyPass Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874367/conditional-proxypass-apache)), but couldn't find exactly what I need.

How would you go about doing that? Is Apache actually able to do that?

Comment: I assume you're asking about matching in the POST request body. I don't think that's possible with Apache. nginx might be able to do it. What you're trying to do is a bit strange. You should try to solve your overall problem in a different way.

Comment: This requires writing a plugin that pre-reads the body, saves it with mod_request, and does mod_rewrite-type stuff to modify the request to be proxied dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure weather it is possible with Apache. But you can achieve this with Nginx with Lua module.

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module

With Lua module you can do anything with Request , Response , Request Body Programatically.

Also for reverse proxy it is better to use Nginx as it provide easy and better configuration for reverse proxy , load balancing.